# python - Jumping in pygame

Tags: python, pygame

I want to edit on the following jump code.

I want to make the character jump fast (decrease **jump_count**), but in each decreasing of **jump_count** I want the value of maximum height of jump stay same. without any changing. Can you help me?

---

**More explain**:

jump_count = 10

jump_height = 0.6

maximum height of jump= -36.999999999999986

---

jump_count = 5

jump_height = ???

maximum height of jump= -36.999999999999986

---

jump_count = 3

jump_height = ???

maximum height of jump= -36.999999999999986

---

Code:

```
class Character:
    def __init__(self):
        # Position
        self.x = 70
        self.y = 194

        # Move
        self.velocity = 10

        # jump:
        self.is_jump = False

        # Jump count
        self.jump_count_range = 10
        self.jump_count = self.jump_count_range

        # Jump height
        self.constant_jump_height_range = 0.6
        self.jump_height = self.constant_jump_height_range

    def Jump(self):
        if self.is_jump:
            if self.jump_count >= -1 * self.jump_count_range:
                neg = 1
                if self.jump_count < 0:
                    neg = -1
                self.y -= (self.jump_count ** 2) * self.jump_height * neg
                self.jump_count -= 1
            else:
                self.is_jump = False
                self.jump_count = self.jump_count_range
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add something like  `max_jump_height`, like this

```py
class Character:
    def __init__(self):
        # Position
        self.x = 70
        self.y = 194

        # Move
        self.velocity = 10

        # jump:
        self.is_jump = False

        # Jump count
        self.jump_count_range = 10
        self.jump_count = self.jump_count_range

        # Jump height
        self.constant_jump_height_range = 0.6
        self.jump_height = self.constant_jump_height_range
        self.max_jump_height = -36.999999999999986

    def Jump(self):
        if self.is_jump:
            if self.jump_count >= -1 * self.jump_count_range:
                neg = 1
                if self.jump_count < 0:
                    neg = -1
                if self.max_jump_height < (self.jump_count ** 2) * self.jump_height * neg:
                    return
                else:
                    self.y -= (self.jump_count ** 2) * self.jump_height * neg
                    self.jump_count -= 1
            else:
                self.is_jump = False
                self.jump_count = self.jump_count_range
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this instead:

```
 float JumpVelocity, 
 float JumpDampening=0.1f;   

 void Jump()
 {
     JumpVelocity = 0.5f;    
     gameObject.rigidbody.useGravity = false;
 }

 void FixedUpdate()
 {
     Vector3 pos = transform.position;
     
     if (JumpVelocity != 0)
     {
         pos.y += JumpVelocity;
         JumpVelocity -= JumpDampening;
         if (JumpVelocity <= 0)
         {
             gameObject.rigidbody.useGravity = true;
             JumpVelocity = 0;
         }
     }

     transform.position = pos;
 }
```

In the above gravity on the object is off when jumping up, turned back on at the peak of the jump arc so gravity takes over again to bring the GO down. Play with higher start values in JumVelocity for quicker jumps, higher values in JumpDampening to slow the jump down quicker or lower values to let the jump get higher and have a more noticeable arc.

or you could just play around with the gravity by doing

```
if(inAir) { // most code has something like this already
   Vector3 vel = rigidbody.velocity;
   vel.y-=BONUS_GRAV*Time.deltaTime;
   rigidbody.velocity=vel;
   ...
 }
```